# ionic commend is not recoganized in windows 7

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

hi i have installed ionic

nodejs version - 4.3.1

npm version - 2.14.12

git version - 2.7.1

cordova version - 6.0.0

when i type ionic in c:\users\pranav

```
   C:\Users\pranav>ionic
      _             _
     (_)           (_)
      _  ___  _ __  _  ___
     | |/ _ \| '_ \| |/ __|
     | | (_) | | | | | (__
     |_|\___/|_| |_|_|\___|  CLI v1.7.14

     Usage: ionic task args

     =======================
```

but when i type in this dir i get  c:\users\pranav\mob app\ionic

```
   C:\Users\pranav\mob app>ionic
   'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

why and how i solve this..any one help me?

Comment: You have to set ionic as a global variable to have it accessable everywhere.

Comment: @SWiggels how to do that?

Comment: Find the location of `ionic.exe`, typically it's where you installed `ionic` in the first place. Then add it to the PATH

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have ionic.cmd should i mention this one or .exe file in path

Comment: You should add its *folder* in the path, not the filename itself. Eg if the file's full path is `C:\Program Files\Ionic\ionic.cmd`, you should add `c:\Program Files\Ionic` in the PATH

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to add anything to the path to be able to use ionic or cordova.

Ionic and cordova are npm modules that should be installed with the -g switch :

```
npm install -g cordova
npm install -g ionic
```

the -g switch means the installed module will be available globaly (means accessible from anywhere).

When you install a npm module with -g, it's installed in the **%appdata%\npm folder**, so in your case **C:\Users\pranav\AppData\Roaming\npm** and this folder should have been automatically added to the path when you installed npm.

Answer (score -1):

**How to add iconic to your PATH:**

I don't know what system you run exactly. If you do not run win 8 or 10 you can look up the answer here: [How to set PATH-variable in windows.](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

> Setting the path and variables in Windows 8 and Windows 10
>
> From the Desktop, right-click the very bottom left corner of the
>   screen to get the Power User Task Menu. From the Power User Task Menu,
>   click System. Click the Advanced System Settings link in the left
>   column. In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab,
>   then click the Environment Variables button near the bottom of that
>   tab. In the Environment Variables window (pictured below), highlight
>   the Path variable in the "System variables" section and click the Edit
>   button. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you want the
>   computer to access. Each different directory is separated with a
>   semicolon as shown below.
>
> C:\Program Files;C:\Winnt;C:\Winnt\System32

EDIT: Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos for his comment. Im sorry for that misleading vocabulary. I corrected it.

Comment: that's k but i am asking which file i should mention in path to set ionic as global??

Comment: i am using windows 7

Comment: @Swiggels Environment variables (not global variables) are one thing. The PATH is a different thing. It isn't polite to say that the OP should have googled for the answer, without giving a good and accurate answer

Comment: Thanks panagiotis-kanavos for your comment I mixed up the vocabulary. I meant PATH-variables. I corrected my answer.